# Can't Access JSON Array of Objects, Driving Me Crazy

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, jquery

I've been stuck on this for a day now and I'm goin' insane. Probably something really simple, but here goes.

I've got a jQuery.Ajax method that calls a WebMethod which retrieves a list of Orders. The jQuery method is this...

```
/* Get orders by the current logged in employee's department */
    function getOrdersByDept(department, filter, dateFrom, dateTo) {
        var dto = {};
        dto['department'] = department;
        dto['filter'] = filter;
        dto['dateFrom'] = dateFrom;
        dto['dateTo'] = dateTo;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ProcessPO.aspx/GetOrdersByDept',
            data: JSON.stringify(dto),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                displayOrders(data.d);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

Returns this JSON...

[image: Orders]

From this WebMethod...

```
[WebMethod]
    public static List<Order> GetOrdersByDept(Department department, Filter filter, DateTime? dateFrom = null, DateTime? dateTo = null)
    {
        return OrderLists.GetOrdersByDepartment(department, filter, dateFrom, dateTo);
    }
```

Now here is the displayOrders code...

```
/* Fill the orders table. */
    function displayOrders(data) {
        $('#gdvOrders tbody').empty();
        for (var key in data) {
            var altRow;
            if (key % 2 == 0)
                altRow = 'class="alt-row"';
            else
                altRow = '';
            /* Convert JSON formatted date to readable short date format */
            var orderDate = data[key].OrderDate.substr(6);
            var currentTime = new Date(parseInt(orderDate));
            var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
            var day = currentTime.getDate();
            var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
            orderDate = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;

            var orderStatus;
            switch (data[key].Status) {
                case 0:
                    orderStatus = 'Pending';
                    break;
                case 1:
                    orderStatus = 'Closed';
                    break;
            }
            $('#gdvOrders tbody').append($('<tr ' + altRow + '><td>' + data.d[key].OrderId + '</td>' +
                                                '<td>' + orderDate + '</td>' +
                                                '<td>' + data[key].EmployeeName + '</td>' +
                                                '<td>' + data[key].Items + '</td>' +
                                                '<td>$' + data[key].SubTotal.toFixed(2) + '</td>' +
                                                '<td>$' + data[key].TaxTotal.toFixed(2) + '</td>' +
                                                '<td>$' + data[key].GrandTotal.toFixed(2) + '</td>' +
                                                '<td>' + orderStatus + '</td></tr>'));
        }
        $('#gdvOrders tbody td:nth-child(4)').hide();
        $('#gdvOrders tbody td:nth-child(5)').hide();
        $('#gdvOrders tbody td:nth-child(6)').hide();
    }
```

Each order holds a property of Items which is a List basically. I store that in the 4th column of the table and hide it. When a user clicks a row/order in the table I want to load another list of each Item into the other table. The click function for the row of orders stripped down for your viewing is this....

```
$('#gdvOrders tbody tr').live('click', function () {
            displayItems($(this).find('td:nth-child(4)').text());
});
```

Now the displayItems function is defined as this...

```
function displayItems(data)
```

I've tried many different ways to iterate through the data which when I...

```
alert(data)
```

I receive...

```
[object Object], [object Object]
```

When I try to iterate through it (tried several different ways) I get undefined, or a character such as [ when I try data[0], data[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U33tC.jpg) would display o and so on and so on. Basically just giving me back each character of [object Object] instead of the object in the array. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you post an example of the JSON you're getting back from the web service?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
        success: function (data) {
            displayOrders(data.d);
        },
```

Comment: Didn't solve my problem but made my code better so that I dont have to iterate through data.d[key].propertyName and can now just do data[key].propertName.

Answer (score 1):

Change these lines

```
data: '{"department": "' + department + '", "filter": "' + filter + '", "dateFrom": "' + dateFrom + '", "dateTo": "' + dateTo + '"}',
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
dataType: 'json',
```

to simply

```
data: dataObj, 
dataType: 'json',
```

before ajax create your data in json object or array as per your convenience

```
var dataObj = {};
dataObj['department'] = department;
dataObj['filter'] = filter;
dataObj['dateFrom'] = dateFrom;
dataObj['dateTo'] = dateTo;
```

and use this dataObj in data and remove contentType, while sending the data jquery itself will convert the dataObj into key value pair like this

`department=valueofdepartment&filter=valueoffilter&....`

Comment: The method to get the orders and display into the table works fine, although I did switch it to your method as it's cleaner, so thanks for that. It's the fact that the returned (data) contains the orders which as I said, displays fine, but each order has data[key].Items which I hide the column in the orders (html)table but it does hold the Item array of objects. But when I call displayOrders(data) it iterates through it like [ o b j e c t O b j e c t] , [ o b j e c t O b j e c t] etc... for each data[0], data[1], data[2], etc...

Comment: Also I had to write data: JSON.stringify(dataObj) for it to work.

Comment: In that first comment I mean to say displayItems(data) not displayOrders(data) that I can't iterate through.

Comment: @user1066133 I still dont understand why you are having the `contentType` parameter used.... you are converting the JSON to the string... and then tying to pass as a json obj... My Suggestion: jQuery serializes the array internally... you need not serialise it nor stringify it...

Comment: @user1066133 so forst of all get rid of `contentType` parameter and dont `stringify` the `dto` object.... you can directly get the details in following way `Request.Form("department")` or `Request.Form("filter")`.. thats it done...

Comment: I don't have access to Request within the static WebMethod?

Comment: I tried your recommendations and get an error now. When I add the stringify it works. And since I can't access the Request object inside the static WebMethod, it's going to have to stay this way for now.

Answer (score 1):

Did you get this far without using the console ?

`alert()` will not display an object, you should use `console.log(data)` to see the objects structure, and then do:

```
var key2 = data.key1.key2
```

etc...

To iterate use

```
$.each(data, function(index, item) {
  console.log(item); 
});
```

or (which is already being used in your script ? )

```
for (var key in data) {
   console.log(data[key]);
}
```

On the other hand, this:

```
$(this).find('td:nth-child(4)').text();
```

will give you a string of text, not an object, hence the name `text()`, and that is what you are passing to the `displayItems()` functions, a textstring, or in your case you're probably not hitting the target and passing nothing.

When doing `text[4]` on a string, it gets you the fifth letter in the string of text.

Try doing :

```
$('#gdvOrders tbody tr').live('click', function () {
    var data = $(this).find('td:nth-child(4)').text();
    console.log(data);
    displayItems(data);
});
```

And see what the console says ? And consider moving to on() if using a newer version of jQuery.

Comment: console.log display 0 = [ 0 = o 0 = b 0 = j etc... Same problem.

Answer (score 0):

So the end result had to be in the line for displayOrders...

```
+ '<td>' + data[key].Items + '</td>' +
```

I had to use..

```
+ '<td>' + JSON.stringify(data[key].Items) + '</td>' +
```

And in the line

```
$('#gdvOrders tbody tr').live('click', function () {
    displayItems($(this).find('td:nth-child(4)').text());
});
```

I had to change it to...

```
$('#gdvOrders tbody tr').live('click', function () {
    displayItems(JSON.parse($(this).find('td:nth-child(4)').text()));
});
```

Which then allowed me to iterate through it with...

```
function displayItems(data) {
    for (var key in data) {
        /* this can be accessed like */
        data[key].PropertyName
    }
}
```

Seems like a bit of conversioning happening but it works. Thanks all for your input!

Answer (score 0):

This problem is similar to mine that, after AJAX, I lost the access to the OO JS class members. The solution is simple. Before you call $.getJSON(), do 'var obj = this;' and then you can access all your class members/resources after .done().